# MassTransit object with abstract property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am working with MassTransit. I have following model situation:

```
public abstract class MyBase {
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass1 : MyBase  {
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass2 : MyBase  {
    public string PropertyC {get;set;}
}

public class MyMessage {
    public string PropertyD { get; set; }
    public MyBase PropertyE { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to publish is `MyMessage` object.

It seems to be working well on publisher but not on the consumer.

The error I am getting is:

> Could not create an instance of type MyBaseClass. Type is an interface
>   or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Which makes a lot of sense to me.

Is there any option to force `MassTransit` to decide which class is that based on concrete type?

EDIT:
Same type is working well in DataService, where it's serialized and deserialized as well.

Comment: Is the error coming from Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: yes it is: at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject.....

Comment: Then I assume this is not really related to MassTransit, is it? As soon as you make that JSON deserialisable by JSON.Net, it will work... You can pick up the JSON from the error queue.

Comment: In fact, I would try using interfaces instead but this might not work for you really if you want to get all the derived class properties deserialised as well.

Comment: You may review: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/message-contracts.html

Comment: Yeah I found that as well. I was trying to play a little bit with settings of JsonSerializerSettings, according to the documentation it should bring type names to messages, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Generally this type of inheritance based message class structure with abstract classes is frowned upon. Sort of like, you know, on an airplane.

Comment: well I thought if DataService deals with that (and use serialization as well), nosql database deals with it as well by defining all possible types and later match is made on properties. I wasn't expecting any problems. I decided to go other way, and just sending different messages depends on type and later map it to right type in consumer.